# Opencart: 3 Buttons in "Add to Cart" Success notification

Tags: php, opencart

I had given a lot of try in achieving this, but i think i was not doing good enough as it was not working.

In opencart, when user click on Add to Cart, he is shown a "Success notification in popup" with a text "Success you have added ITEM to your cart".

I want to add 3 buttons in this popup.

1. Continue shopping: It will Close the popup
2. Buy Now: redirect to checkout.
3. View Cart: redirect to cart.

i tried modifying catalog/language/english/checkout/cart.php with below code but not successful.

```
   <div class="checkout">
  <a class="button" id="close_cart"><?php echo $this->language->get('theme_close'); ?></a> 
  <a href="<?php echo $cart; ?>" class="button"><?php echo $text_cart; ?></a>
  <a href="<?php echo $checkout; ?>" id="checkout-button" class="button"><?php echo $text_checkout; ?></a>
</div>
```

I am not aware if its possible to edit this catalog/language/english/checkout/cart.php as it contains messages. As i find the pop up text in this cart.php so tried editing it.

I inserted above code in `$_['text_success']` in cart.php

Could you please help..I have also attached a snapshot what i want to achieve.[image]

Comment: use this one extension  http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=9431

Comment: @ravi patel: Its very different what i was looking for. I just need simple 3 buttons with their default functionality..Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were trying very correctly - You indeed need to modify the `$_['text_success']` in mentioned language file, so that it looks like this (re-using Your code):

```
$_['text_success'] = 'Success: You have added <a href="%s">%s</a> to your <a href="%s">shopping cart</a>!<div class="checkout"><a class="button" id="close_cart">Continue Shopping</a><a href="index.php?route=checkout/checkout" id="checkout-button" class="button">Buy Now</a><a href="index.php?route=checkout/cart" class="button">View Cart</a></div>';
```

**notice that all the `<?php echo ... ?>` are replaced by corresponding strings only**.

For closing this success notice by clicking on *Continue Shopping* link You need to register a *click* event listener, e.g. in `catalog/view/javascript/common.js` add this somewhere at the end:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#close_cart').on('click', function() {
        $('.success').remove();
    });
});
```

This was not the scope of the question so consider it as extra value to the answer...

Comment: Thanks for your response. Its working fine. But first thing, All 3 buttons are connected :-)..There is no spacing between buttons as in attached snapshot..2nd thing. can you please tell, if user clicks on Continue Shopping, how this popup will be closed..Thanks

Comment: I have added &nbsp; for space...But still i am not able to close popup if user click on Continue button..